# How to test default exported javascript module in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have a `module.js` file with content like this

```
export default {
    foo(),
    bar()
}
```

I have tried doing this on my test file

```
jest.mock('/module/path', () => {
  foo: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)
})

import Module from './module/path'
```

and this is the test that I'm trying to do

```
  test('test the module', () => {
    let fooSpy= jest.spyOn(Module, 'foo')

    vm.methodThatUseFoo()

    expect(fooSpy).toBeCalled()
  })
```

and this is the error that I encountered

`Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`

Answer (score 2):

This syntax doesn't work as expected:

```
jest.mock('/module/path', () => {
  foo: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)
})
```

Arrow function returns `undefined` because `foo` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Implicit return should be parsed as an object:

```
jest.mock('/module/path', () => ({
  foo: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)
}))
```

Or considering that it's default export, it more likely should be:

```
jest.mock('/module/path', () => ({
  default: {
    foo: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)
  }
}))
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but unfortunately it's still error, the error is different though, `Cannot spy the foo property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`, any suggestion?

Comment: The error suggests what could be possibly wrong. You need to consistently use default export. Make sure original module is imported as default where it's used in tested code, mock it with `default` key. You don't need to spy on it because jest.mock already makes `Module.default.foo` a spy.

Comment: I'm sorry I still dont understand, if jest.mock already makes it a spy, then how do I test that the `foo` is called?

i've tried `expect(Module.foo).toBeCalled()` but it's not working

Comment: What was the error in this case? It's Module.default.foo, not Module.foo, at least from what you posted.

Comment: The spy doesn't seem to work, the errors are: ```expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0```

Comment: Can you provide a way to replicate the problem? If the module was mocked, imported and then imported function was called, the spy is expected to be called.